# Do Standard errors and percentage of valid instances from same data set effects the F1 score?

Tags: reliability, precision-recall, validity

Considering we have a data set of `944` elements. One with 45% valid instances (433 instances) and the other with 73.8% valid instances (697 instances). The F1 score for the first group with lower valid instances is higher than the other. Is there any statically measurement that includes the number of instances into the consideration?